# Dropping the 'table' for a model and recreating in a django south migration

Tags: python, django, orm, database-migration, django-south

I have a django model which is created using some custom sql. It's actually just a SQL view, it's not a real table. We are using django south to manage migrations. I have changed the view definition SQL, and I want to write a migration for this change.

Since it's just a sql view, if I drop the view, then 'recreate' it (by running the custom sql), then the view will be updated to the new defintion and we, obviously won't lose any data. How can I do that in django south?

Deleteing the table/view is easy in django south, I could just call some raw SQL `db.execute*("DROP VIEW view_name;")`, is there a better way?

Is there a way to recreate the table from an object? something like `orm.MyTable.recreate_this_table()`, so that it'll use the custom sql file?

Answer (score 2):

[How to handle database views in Django/South](http://christiankaula.com/how-to-handle-database-views-django-south.html) seems to contain some good information about this issue. As for the end of your question, I'm not sure I understand what you want to do...

Comment: Oh... I didn't see the date it was posted... how did I get here ? :P

Comment: hah, at least there's an answer for the next unsuspecting traveller